# Duplicate Question Detection

Tags: feature-request, duplicate-questions

I know stackexchange organized a competition recently on automatic duplicate detection. I noticed recently that if I ask a question on the english stackexchange site, which could easily be detected by making an appropriate use of dictionary, such as this question:

[Is it correct to use multiple brackets in a sentence?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/91775/23918)

I was suspecting there could be duplicates and I went through the suggestions without seeing one, yet it could have been guessed with a good synonym detection algorithm. I'm guessing this could be due to the absence or incompleteness of a synonym dictionary.

Also, I don't understand why the first paragraph on a question that has been closed by moderators as 'Exact Duplicate' has the words 'Possible Duplicate'. I think there should be a conformity there.

Comment: That competition was for [detecting closed questions](http://www.kaggle.com/c/predict-closed-questions-on-stack-overflow) for reasons *other* than exact duplicates.

Comment: Oops, guess I had been misinformed. But I think the question still stands anyway? Or don't you think it would make sense?

Comment: There's a lot of wording that is contradictory, this is one of those places (we say "possible" when we close it as "exact", for instance).  It's one of the quirks of the site, if you will.